# What is the lowest version of Dart available for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the lowest version of Dart available for Flutter?
I am a developer of a library for Flutter.
This library needs to be available to all Flutter app developers.

I would like to use the Dart 2 features in my library, but if a user of the library is developing a Flutter app in Dart 1 then they cannot use my library.

Can I use the Dart 2 features in my library?
Is anyone developing a Flutter app on Dart 1? (Is it possible to develop a Flutter app in Dart 1?)

Comment: There is not really a good reason to develop below Flutter `stable`. So `2.8.0` should be fine as a lowest version right now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/https-medium-com-rahman-sameeha-whats-flutter-an-intro-to-dart-6fc42ba7c4a3/) from freecodecamp:

*Google had its first-ever release of **Flutter 1.0** last December, after having it in beta mode for over 18 months. Dart is the programming language used to code Flutter apps. Dart is another product by Google and released **version 2.1**, before Flutter, in November.*

So, the first stable version of flutter (Flutter 1.0) is using Dart version 2.1

I hope it will be helpful.